# Xamarin iOS - Custom font does not appear in main storyboard

Tags: ios, xamarin, fonts

so I need to use custom font for my project the font is AgencyFB Bold the so what i did is

1. Imported the file in the resources folder
2. Added the UIAppfonts in info.plist
3. Set the bundle action to bundleresources

and the properties to and do not copy
The problem is that the font stopped showing in the storyboard editor i get it to work once after restarting Visual Studio a few times ,but since then i cannot get it to work it just does not appear in the custom fonts. I have tried with re-importing the file, reinstalled Visual Studio, Confirmed that i have entered the correct name of the font in the info.plist with the extension and it's still the same.  Can someone please help me i'm stuck at this for whole day already. Thank you in advance!

Comment: i have the same issue after updating xamarin and visual studio... maybe its a bug of the update

Answer (score 0):

It is normal issue online, The best solution is using custom font **in code**.

You can also file this in [Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/).

Refer to

[Using Custom Fonts in the Storyboard](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/29310/using-custom-fonts-in-the-storyboard)

[Custom Font not showing in Xamarin Storyboard](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/62954/custom-font-not-showing-in-xamarin-storyboard)

[Xamarin iOS Using a Custom Font](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/37301/xamarin-ios-using-a-custom-font)

Answer (score 0):

Right Click and Open the Xib or storyboard file in Source Code Editor, search the control and specify the font manually.
Eg:
fontDescription key="fontDescription" name="OpenSans-Bold" family="Open Sans" pointSize="32"